# kubectl create pod using override return error: Invalid JSON Patch

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to run my pod using below command but keep getting error:

```
error: Invalid JSON Patch
```

```
kubectl run -i tmp-pod --rm -n=my-scripts --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides= "$(cat pod.json)"
```

Here is my `pod.json` file:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "test",
        "namespace": "my-ns",
        "labels": {
            "app": "test"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "image": "myimage",
                "command": [
                    "python",
                    "/usr/bin/cma/excute.py"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of testing and it seems there is an issue with Cmder not executing `$()` properly - either not working at all, or treating newlines as <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and thus executing a commant before entire JSON is passed.

You may want to try running your commands in PowerShell:

```
kubectl run -i tmp-pod --rm -n=my-scripts --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides=$(Get-Content pod.json -Raw)
```

---

There is a similar issue on GitHub *[[Windows] kubectl run not accepting valid JSON as --override on Windows (same JSON works on Mac) #519](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/519)*. Unfortunately, there is no clear solution for this.

Possible solutions are:

- Passing JSON as a string directly

  ```
  kubectl run -i tmp-pod --rm -n=my-scripts --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides='{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{...}}'
  ```
- Using `'` instead of `"` around overrides.
- Using triple quotes `"""` instead of single quotes `"` in JSON file.